# Unity: Singleton DontDestroyOnLoad Build Error

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, singleton

I am using XMGUnityLib Plugin. The program runs fine in the editor without any error but when I try to build it (Android) then while at pushing apk step it gives this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The following game object is invoking the DontDestroyOnLoad method: AnalyticsManager. Notice that DontDestroyOnLoad can only be used in play mode and, as such, cannot be part of an editor script.
XMGSingleton`1[XMGAnalyticsManager].get_Instance () (at Assets/XMG/UnityLib/Util/XMGSingleton.cs:28)
AndroidStorePostProcess.OnPostprocessScene () (at Assets/Editor/AndroidStorePostProcess.cs:32)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

XMGSingleton.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

/// <summary>
/// XMG singleton base Class.
/// Inherit your Manager Monobehavior classes that you want to be Singletons
/// </summary>
public abstract class XMGSingleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected static T instance;
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the instance of this singleton
    /// Make sure we don't get destroyed on Scene Load
    /// </summary>
    public static T Instance {
        get {
            
            if(instance == null) {
                instance = (T) FindObjectOfType(typeof(T));
            
                if (instance == null) {
                   Debug.LogError("An instance of " + typeof(T) + 
                      " is needed in the scene, but there is none.");
                    return null;
                }

                DontDestroyOnLoad(instance.gameObject);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    #region Public Methods

    public static bool HasInstance {
        get {
            if( (T) FindObjectOfType(typeof(T)) != null ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper to cast the Instance to the Type provided
    /// </summary>
    public static Type MyInstance<Type> () {
        return (Type)(object)Instance;
    }
    
    #endregion
}
```

XMGAnalyticsManager.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Com.XMG.UnityLib.Community.OnlineGame;
using Com.XMG.UnityLib.Tracking;
    
#if UNITY_IPHONE
    using FlurryAccess = FlurryBinding;
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
    using FlurryAccess = FlurryAndroid;
#endif

public abstract partial class XMGAnalyticsManager : XMGSingleton<XMGAnalyticsManager> {
    
    #region Private Fields
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The type of the current build.
    /// For Analytics QA testing point to Analytics
    /// For QA Testing point to SandBox
    /// For Production/Release build point to Production
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField]
    private BuildTypeEnum buildType = BuildTypeEnum.SandBox;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The type of the android store type
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField]
    private AndroidStoreTypeEnum androidStoreType = AndroidStoreTypeEnum.Google;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The swrve authentication Info
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField]
    private SwrveAuthentication swrveAuth;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The flurry auth.
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField]
    private FlurryAuthentication flurryAuth;
    
    /// <summary>
    ///  Sends events every X seconds.
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField]
    private float sendEventsEverySeconds = 30;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The parent screen.
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField]
    private string parentScreen = "SplashPage";
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The grand parent screen.
    /// </summary>
    string grandParentScreen = "null";
    
    /// <summary>
    /// My external IP.
    /// </summary>
    string myExtIP = "";
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The swrve component.
    /// </summary>
    private SwrveComponent swrveComponent;
    
    private Dictionary<string, JSONObject> swrveResources = new Dictionary<string, JSONObject>();
    /// <summary>
    /// Resource hashmap ----> (key: resource name, value: json object)
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, JSONObject> Resources {
        get {
            return this.swrveResources;
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// This event is triggered when swrve data is updated.
    /// </summary>
    public static event Action ItemsConfigurationUpdatedEvent = delegate {};
    
    /// <summary>
    /// True if we are in the fetching of AB Test Data State
    /// </summary>
    private bool isFetchingABParams = false;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The current swrve identifier.
    /// </summary>
    private string currentSwrveId = null;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The android bundle version.
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField]
    protected string androidBundleVersion = "1.0";
    
    #endregion
    
    #region Public Properties
    
    /// <summary>
    /// True if it's a production build
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsProductionBuild {
        get { return buildType == BuildTypeEnum.Production; }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the type of the android store.
    /// </summary>
    public AndroidStoreTypeEnum AndroidStoreType {
        get { return androidStoreType; }
        set { androidStoreType = value; }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// True if its a google play store build
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsGoogleStoreType {
        get { return androidStoreType == AndroidStoreTypeEnum.Google; }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// True if its an Amazon store build
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsAmazonStoreType {
        get { return androidStoreType == AndroidStoreTypeEnum.Amazon; }
    }
    
    #endregion
    
    #region Monobehaviors & Init
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Add event Listeners
    /// </summary>
    void Awake() {
        XMGOnlineProfileManager.OnProfileLoadedEvent += ProfileHasLoadedCallback;
        XMGCommunityManager.OnCreateRealProfileOnServerEvent += ProfileCreatedOnServerCallback;
        XMGCommunityManager.OnNewFriendsAddedEvent += NewFriendsAddedCallback;
        
        RegisterGameListeners();
        // TODO: Listen for Profile Change events
        swrveAuth.Init();
        flurryAuth.Init();
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the SWRVE Event timer
    /// </summary>
    void Start() {
        StartSwrveTimer();
        StartCoroutine( CheckIP() );
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks for the IP
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The IP
    /// </returns>
    IEnumerator CheckIP(){

        WWW myExtIPWWW = new WWW("http://checkip.dyndns.org");
    
        if( myExtIPWWW != null ) {
            yield return myExtIPWWW;
            
            if( myExtIPWWW.error == null ) {
        
                myExtIP=myExtIPWWW.text;
            
                myExtIP=myExtIP.Substring(myExtIP.IndexOf(":")+1);
            
                myExtIP=myExtIP.Substring(0,myExtIP.IndexOf("<"));
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Detach event Listeners
    /// </summary>
    void OnDestroy() {
        XMGOnlineProfileManager.OnProfileLoadedEvent -= ProfileHasLoadedCallback;
        XMGCommunityManager.OnCreateRealProfileOnServerEvent -= ProfileCreatedOnServerCallback;
        XMGCommunityManager.OnNewFriendsAddedEvent -= NewFriendsAddedCallback;
        UnRegisterGameListeners();
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// If Pause end session
    /// If Resume Start session and Re-Login.
    /// At any case post events
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='pause'>
    /// Pause.
    /// </param>
    void OnApplicationPause(bool pause) {
        if (currentSwrveId != null) {
            
            if(pause) {
                swrveComponent.Swrve_AddSessionEnd();
            } else {
                swrveComponent.Swrve_AddSessionStart();
                SessionStart();
                AnalyticsLogout();
                AnalyticsLogin();
            }
            
            LogUserProperties();
            swrveComponent.Swrve_PostEvents(currentSwrveId, SWRVE_APP_VERSION);
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Init plugins.The Profile Has loaded
    /// </summary>
    void ProfileHasLoadedCallback() {
        // Get Swrve component
        swrveComponent = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<SwrveComponent>();
        AnalyticsLogin();
        
        // Check if we've set the random user property, if not then set it
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(RANDOM_TEST_PROPERTY_KEY)) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(RANDOM_TEST_PROPERTY_KEY, "true");

            JSONObject userProperty = new JSONObject(JSONObject.Type.OBJECT);
            int random = NGUITools.RandomRange(1, 100);
            userProperty.AddField("RandNum", random.ToString());
            
            swrveComponent.Swrve_AddUserUpdateEvent(userProperty.ToString());
        }
        
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// A new Online Profile created callback.
    /// </summary>
    void ProfileCreatedOnServerCallback() {
        AddNamedEvent( "Community.FacebookUserCreated" );
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// New friends were added callback.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='newFriendsAdded'>
    /// The New friends added
    /// </param>
    void NewFriendsAddedCallback( int newFriendsAdded ) {
        JSONObject jTournamentFriends = new JSONObject(JSONObject.Type.OBJECT);
        jTournamentFriends.AddField( "NewFriendsAdded", BucketGeneral( newFriendsAdded ) );
        AddNamedEvent ( "Community.TournamentAddedFriend", jTournamentFriends );
    }
    
    #endregion
    
    #region Abstract & Virtual Methods
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the tracking Object
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract XMGTracking GetTracking();
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the game listeners.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract void RegisterGameListeners();
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Unregister the game listeners.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract void UnRegisterGameListeners();
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs the game user properties.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='jUserProperties'>
    /// The JSON Object with the user properties.
    /// </param>
    protected abstract void LogGameUserProperties(JSONObject jUserProperties);
    
    /// <summary>
    /// A session Is Started
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract void SessionStart();
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The session has ended
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract void SessionEnd();
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the user start time.
    /// Default to Now
    /// Override to provide the user's start time
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The user start time.
    /// </returns>
    protected virtual long GetUserStartTime() {
        return (long)XMGUnityUtil.ToUnixTimeFromUniversal( DateTime.UtcNow );
    }
    
    #endregion
    
    #region Private Methods
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the swrve timer.
    /// </summary>
    private void StartSwrveTimer() {
        StartCoroutine( StartEventsTimer());
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs the user properties.
    /// And Calls abstract LogGameUserProperties
    /// </summary>
    private  void LogUserProperties() {
        JSONObject jUserProperties = new JSONObject(JSONObject.Type.OBJECT);
        // Add here Common User Properties
        XMGTracking tracking = GetTracking();
        
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_FIRST_LAUNCH_DAY, tracking.FirstLaunch.Day );
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_FIRST_LAUNCH_MONTH, tracking.FirstLaunch.Month );
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_FIRST_LAUNCH_YEAR, tracking.FirstLaunch.Year );
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_FIRST_LAUNCH_EPOCH, XMGUnityUtil.ToUnixTimeFromUniversal( tracking.FirstLaunch ).ToString() );
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_TOTAL_TAPJOY_REWARDS, tracking.TotalTapJoyPointsEarned );
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_TOTAL_SPONSORPAY_REWARDS, tracking.TotalSponsorPayPointsEarned );
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_TOTAL_CHARTBOOST_ADS_CLICKED, tracking.TotalChartBoostAdsClicked );
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_TOTAL_CHARTBOOST_ADS_CLOSED, tracking.TotalChartBoostAdsClosed );
        
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_TOTAL_SOFT_CURRENCY_EARNED, tracking.SoftCurrencyEarned );
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_TOTAL_HARD_CURRENCY_EARNED, tracking.HardCurrencyEarned );
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_TOTAL_SOFT_CURRENCY_SPENT, tracking.SoftCurrencySpent );
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_TOTAL_HARD_CURRENCY_SPENT, tracking.HardCurrencySpent );
#if UNITY_IPHONE
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_VERION, EtceteraTwoBinding.getInfoPlistValue("CFBundleVersion") );
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_VERION, androidBundleVersion );
#endif
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_TOTAL_FRIENDS, tracking.TotalFriends );
        jUserProperties.AddField( UP_TOTAL_UNIQUE_DAYS_PLAYED, tracking.TotalUniqueDaysPlayed );
        if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( myExtIP ) ) {
            jUserProperties.AddField( UP_IP, myExtIP );
        }
        LogGameUserProperties(jUserProperties);
        swrveComponent.Swrve_AddUserUpdateEvent(jUserProperties.ToString());
    }
    
    #endregion
    
    #region Authentication
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs in to Flurry and SWRVE
    /// </summary>
    void AnalyticsLogin() {

        FlurryLogin();
        
        if( currentSwrveId != null ) {
            if( !currentSwrveId.Equals( XMGOnlineProfileManager.Instance.ActiveOnlineProfile.GameStats.SwrveId ) ) {
                Debug.Log("There is already a swrve account signed in!!! You must close the session first!");
                AnalyticsLogout();
            } else {
                // This swrve user is already logged in, bail out of this function
                Debug.Log("Attempt to log into swrve twice with the same id... Ignoring.");
                return;
            }
        }
        
        SwrveLogin(XMGOnlineProfileManager.Instance.ActiveOnlineProfile.GameStats.SwrveId);
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Logout from Flurry and SWRVE
    /// </summary>
    private void AnalyticsLogout() {
        
        FlurryLogout();
        
        if(currentSwrveId == null) {
            Debug.LogError("There is no active swrve user!!! Cannot close session.");
            return;
        }
        
        SwrveLogout();
    }
    
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts Flurry Session
    /// </summary>
    private void FlurryLogin() {
#if UNITY_IPHONE
        FlurryAccess.startSession(flurryAuth.FlurryKey);
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        FlurryAccess.onStartSession(flurryAuth.FlurryKey, true, true );
#endif
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Logouts from Flurry
    /// </summary>
    private void FlurryLogout() {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        FlurryAccess.onEndSession();
#endif
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Login to Swrve
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='swrveId'>
    /// The Swrve identifier.
    /// </param>
    private void SwrveLogin(string swrveId) {
        
        currentSwrveId = swrveId;
        
        int gameId = 0;
        string apiKey = "";
        
        if (buildType == BuildTypeEnum.Analytics) {
            gameId = swrveAuth.AnalyticsGameID;
            apiKey = swrveAuth.AnalyticsAPIKey;
        } else if (buildType == BuildTypeEnum.SandBox) {
            gameId = swrveAuth.SandboxGameID;
            apiKey = swrveAuth.SandboxAPIKey;
        } else if( buildType == BuildTypeEnum.Production ) {
            gameId = swrveAuth.ProductionGameID;
            apiKey = swrveAuth.ProductionAPIKey;
        }
        
        
        InitializeSWRVEComponent(gameId,
                    apiKey,
                    swrveAuth.PersonalKey,
                    swrveAuth.URLABTest
                    );
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Logout from Swrve
    /// </summary>
    private void SwrveLogout() {
        // Make sure to close the Swrve session
        SessionEnd();
        swrveComponent.Swrve_AddSessionEnd();
        swrveComponent.Swrve_PostEvents(currentSwrveId, SWRVE_APP_VERSION);
        currentSwrveId = null;
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the SWRVE component.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='gameId'>
    /// The Game identifier.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name='apiKey'>
    /// The API key.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name='personalKey'>
    /// Personal key.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name='abURL'>
    /// The Ab Test server URL.
    /// </param>
    private void InitializeSWRVEComponent(int gameId, string apiKey, string personalKey, string abURL) {
        swrveComponent.gameId = gameId;
        swrveComponent.apiKey = apiKey;
        swrveComponent.abTestServer = abURL;
        
        // Setup swrve for new user
        swrveComponent.Swrve_AddSessionStart();
        SessionStart();
        if(isFetchingABParams == false) {
            isFetchingABParams = true;
            StartCoroutine(GetAllResourcesWithABTests());
        }
    }
    
    #endregion
    
    #region A/B Helpers
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the most recent JSON configuration for a resource from swrve or NULL if there is none.
    /// This means it could return cached data that is old. If you want to retrieve the latest from swrve.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="itemId">
    /// A <see cref="System.String"/>
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="JSONObject"/>
    /// </returns>
    public JSONObject GetItemParams(string itemId) {
        JSONObject item = null;
        swrveResources.TryGetValue(itemId, out item);
        return item;
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all resources with AB tests.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The all resources with AB tests.
    /// </returns>
    private IEnumerator GetAllResourcesWithABTests() {
        
        string swrveURLRequest = string.Format(swrveAuth.URLABTestResources + "?api_key={0}&user={1}&joined={2}", swrveComponent.apiKey, currentSwrveId, GetUserStartTime() );
        WWW itemRequest = new WWW(swrveURLRequest);
        yield return itemRequest; // Yield until a result is returned.
        
        if(itemRequest.error != null) {
            Debug.LogWarning("Error attempting to fetch Swrve A/B Resource data: " + itemRequest.error);
            LoadCachedConfig();
            // Bail!
            yield break;
        }
        
        // Process all the resources into a hashmap ( key: resource name,  value: json object )
        JSONObject jResources = new JSONObject(itemRequest.text);
        if(jResources == null || jResources.type == JSONObject.Type.NULL) {
            // Bad data from swrve, abort!
            Debug.LogError("Bad A/B resource data from swrve!");
            LoadCachedConfig();
            yield break;
        } else {
            //Debug.LogWarning( "Data from SWRVE: " + jResources );
        }
        
        XMGSaveLoadUtils.Instance.SaveEncryptedField(CACHED_CONFIG_KEY, itemRequest.text); // Replace the old cached config.
        ParseResources(jResources);
        if( swrveResources.Count > 0 ) {
            ItemsConfigurationUpdatedEvent();
        }
        
        isFetchingABParams = false;
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the cached swrve config file
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadCachedConfig() {
        string cached = XMGSaveLoadUtils.Instance.LoadEncryptedField(CACHED_CONFIG_KEY);
        
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(cached)) {
            // There was no cached data
            return;
        }
        
        // Apply the cached resources so it doesn't block updates.
        JSONObject jResources = new JSONObject(cached);
        ParseResources(jResources);
        if( swrveResources.Count > 0 ) {
            ItemsConfigurationUpdatedEvent();
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    ///  Expects a JSON array of resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="resources">
    /// A <see cref="JSONObject"/>
    /// </param>
    private void ParseResources(JSONObject jResources) {
        swrveResources.Clear();
        //Debug.Log( "Parsing SWRVE Resources: " + jResources );
        
        if(jResources == null || jResources.type != JSONObject.Type.ARRAY) {
            // Bad data from swrve, abort!
            Debug.LogError("Could not parse resource data, unexpected format!");
            return;
        }
        
        foreach(JSONObject data in jResources.list) {
            JSONObject key = data.GetField("uid");
            if(key == null || key.type != JSONObject.Type.STRING || string.IsNullOrEmpty( JSONObject.GetString(key) ) ) {
                // Bad item, on to the next
                Debug.LogWarning("Bad item, no property 'uid' in " + data.print());
                continue;
            }
            // Add the resource over top of any precached configuration
            swrveResources[JSONObject.GetString(key)] = data;
        }
    }
    
    #endregion
    
    #region Event Handling
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the named event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='name'>
    /// The EventName.
    /// </param>
    public void AddNamedEvent(string name) {
        swrveComponent.Swrve_AddNamedEvent(name, "{}");
#if UNITY_IPHONE
        FlurryAccess.logEvent(name, false);
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        FlurryAccess.logEvent(name);
#endif
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a named event with Payload
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='name'>
    /// The EventName.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name='payload'>
    /// Payload.
    /// </param>
    public void AddNamedEvent(string name, JSONObject payload) {
        string data = payload.ToString();
        
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) {
            swrveComponent.Swrve_AddNamedEvent(name, data);
        } else {
            swrveComponent.Swrve_AddNamedEvent(name, "{}");
        }
        
#if UNITY_IPHONE
        FlurryAccess.logEventWithParameters(name, payload.ToDictionary(), false);
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        FlurryAccess.logEvent(name, payload.ToDictionary());
#endif
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Infinite Loop to send events in the queue
    /// </summary>
    private IEnumerator StartEventsTimer() {
        float timeInterval = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        while (true) {
            if(Time.realtimeSinceStartup - timeInterval >= sendEventsEverySeconds) {
                SendEvents();
                timeInterval = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1 );
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the events to SWRVE
    /// </summary>
    private void SendEvents() {
        if(currentSwrveId != null) {
            swrveComponent.Swrve_PostEvents(currentSwrveId, SWRVE_APP_VERSION);
        }
    }
    
    #endregion
    
    #region UI Events
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a UI screen visit event.
    /// Records the current screen, the parent screen, and the grandparent screen.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='screenName'>
    /// Screen name.
    /// </param>
    public void ScreenVisitEvent(string screenName) {
        
        JSONObject eventParams = new JSONObject(JSONObject.Type.OBJECT);
        
        if(parentScreen != null) {
            eventParams.AddField("parent", parentScreen);
        }
        if(grandParentScreen != null) {
            eventParams.AddField("grandParent", grandParentScreen);
        }
        
        AddNamedEvent("UI.Flow." + screenName, eventParams);
        
        eventParams.AddField("screen", screenName);
        AddNamedEvent("UI.Flow.Screens", eventParams);
        
        grandParentScreen = parentScreen;
        parentScreen = screenName;
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a UI button pressed event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='buttonName'>
    /// The Button name.
    /// </param>
    public void ButtonPressedEvent( string buttonName ) {
        AddNamedEvent("UI.ButtonPressed." + buttonName );
    }
    
    #endregion
    
    #region Purchase Events
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends an analytics buy in event for purchasing inapps.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='rewardCurrency'>
    /// Reward currency
    /// </param>
    /// <param name='rewardAmount'>
    ///  Amount of rewardCurrency
    /// </param>
    /// <param name='localCost'>
    /// The real money price in local currency ( e.g 0.99 )
    /// </param>
    /// <param name='localCurrency'>
    /// CAD, USD, etc...
    /// </param>
    public void AddBuyInEvent(string rewardCurrency, int rewardAmount, float localCost, string localCurrency, string itemID ) {
        swrveComponent.Swrve_AddBuyInEvent( "", rewardCurrency, rewardAmount, Mathf.Round(localCost* 100)/100, localCurrency );
        AddNamedEvent( "Purhases.IAP" );
        AddNamedEvent( "Purhases.IAP.HardCurrency" + itemID );
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Analytics event when a user purchases an item in-game.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='itemID'>
    /// The UID for the Item
    /// </param>
    /// <param name='currency'>
    /// The currency
    /// </param>
    /// <param name='itemCost'>
    /// Item cost.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name='itemQuantity'>
    /// Item quantity.
    /// </param>
    public void AddPurchaseEvent( string itemID, string currency, int itemCost, int itemQuantity ) {
        swrveComponent.Swrve_AddPurchaseItemEvent( itemID, currency, itemCost, itemQuantity );
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a purchase conversion event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name='itemID'>
    ///The unique Item ID
    /// </param>
    public void AddPurchaseConversionPackEvent( string itemID ) {
        AddNamedEvent( "Purchases.HardCurrency.SoftCurrency" );
        AddNamedEvent( "Purhases.HardCurrency.SoftCurrency." + itemID );
    }
    
    #endregion
}
```

Is this singleton class correctly coded? If yes, what could be the problem?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: It says that the error is in `XMGInAppManage` but you posted code for `XMGSingleton`...

Comment: updated the question...

Comment: Sorry I don't have XMGUnityLib plugin. Contact the author and report the problem. There is nothing wrong with the XMGSingleton class.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an "Editor Script" that inherits from this class? If so then most probably this is what's causing the error. If you're not sure what this means, try looking for a folder in your project named `Editor` and looking in its scripts. Or try searching for any scripts that are `using UnityEditor;` and that inherit from `Editor` like this: `public class Name : Editor` and make them not inherit from this class.

Another solution is try commenting the DontDestroyOnLoad line (line 26 in XMGSingleton.cs) and put it yourself where you need it.

Go to the objects that you're using this script with and do something like this:

```
void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        instance = this;
    }
    else
        if (instance != this)
            Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the post is a bit old, I recently bumped into this issue. It was a bit confusing because I had not added any new editor script and other editor scripts were not being called from the Singleton GameObject that the error was pointing to.
When I tried restarting Unity and then again created the build, it started giving some other exception.

However, I finally found the issue was being caused by a method from another object (created by the Singleton's OnAwake method) trying to access an uninitialized property of the Singleton (because the OnAwake method execution was not completed).

I fixed it by delaying the other object's method callback based on a different event.